# Update checkbox status when changing element value

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm a beginner in web development and I am working on a webpage where I have some book products you can buy.

Each book has a  quantity between 1-5 which means you can get 1-5 copies of a book.

If I go on a product and select an amount I want the product's checkbox to be checked automatically.

However with my code when I change a product amount every checkbox in the page is checked.

My code :

```js
function updatetotal() {
  var quantities = document.getElementsByClassName("amn");
  var sum = 0;
  var floatprice = parseFloat("9.99");
  var sm = document.getElementById("thesum");
  var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("bought");
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (quantities[i].value != null) { //this is were all boxes in the page are checked and I want only the boxes with amounts not null to be checked
      boxes[i].checked = true;
    }
    sum += quantities[i].value * floatprice;
  }
  sm.innerHTML = sum.toString(); //put the sum next to the cart 
}
```

```html
<!-- a shopping cart which displays my product sum -->
<img src="IMAGES/shopcart.png" id="cart" alt=c art/> = <span id="thesum"> </span> (price of selected products) <!-- I have a total of six books -->


  <div id="p-float">
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\subtle.jpg" alt = subtle_art/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Subtle Art of not giving an F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class="amn" onchange = "updatetotal()"  name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\everything.jpg" alt = every/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Everything is <br/> F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" onchange = "updatetotal()" class = "amn" name = "num"  value = "amount" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>
  
      <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\work.jpg" alt = deepw/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Deep </br>Work </div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number"  class="amn" onchange = "updatetotal()" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>
    
 
   <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\giant.jpg" alt = gnt/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Awaken the giant within</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number"  class="amn" onchange = "updatetotal()" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div> 
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\habits.jpg" alt = hbts/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">7 Habits of highly effective people</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class = "amn" onchange = "updatetotal()" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me" /> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>
      
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\anything.jpg" alt = any/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Achieve anything in 1 year</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class="amn" onchange = "updatetotal()" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>
      
  </div>
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` and `<br>` and `<input>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML. In addition, the `<center>` element has been obsolete for many years. Do not use it.

Comment: @mplungjan That's why this is a comment marked as a "Note". I'm being helpful to one who wants to learn web standards.

Comment: `value="amount "` for a number type input?

Comment: Can you update your snippet to include all required antries? It now throws an error, because your HTML doesn't have all elements assumed to exist by JavaScript.

Comment: The console error is because you need `i < quantities.length` and not `i < 6` in current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change the structure a bit, and wrap each product in a container, you can do something like this. without changing your approach.

but i would suggest you to use javascript event handlers instead of using html event properties.

```js
 function updatetotal(event) {
  var boxes = event.target
  var quantities = boxes.closest(".amn");
  var sum = 0;
  var floatprice = parseFloat("9.99");
  var sm = document.getElementById("thesum");
    if (quantities.value) { //this is were all boxes in the page are checked and I want only the boxes with amounts not null to be checked
      boxes.closest('.product').querySelector('.bought').checked = true;
    } else {
   boxes.closest('.product').querySelector('.bought').checked = false;
 }
 let amountFields = document.querySelectorAll(".amn");
 amountFields.forEach(function(e){
   sum += e.value * floatprice;
 }) 
  sm.innerHTML = sum.toString(); //put the sum next to the cart 
}
```

```html
    <img src="IMAGES/shopcart.png" id="cart" alt=c art/> = <span id="thesum"> </span> (price of selected products) //an instance of a product (I have a total of six books)

    <div class="p-float">
      <div class="p-float-in">
        <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\work.jpg" alt=d eepw/><br/>
          <div class="p-name">Deep <br>Work </div>
          <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
          <div class="product">
            <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" onchange="updatetotal(event)" name="num" value="amount " min="1" max="5" /> </div><br/>
            <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product">
            <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" onchange="updatetotal(event)" name="num" value="amount " min="1" max="5" /> </div><br/>
            <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box1" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product">
            <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" onchange="updatetotal(event)" name="num" value="amount " min="1" max="5" /> </div><br/>
            <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box2" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
          </div>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I removed the console.log - the code does not work correctly - try to change the quantities a few times

Comment: @mplungjan  it works, just run code snippet, and it works. checks only the checkbox associated with current input. unless you are looking for something else

Comment: The amount at the top called sm should be the total sum of all books. If I click up and down a few times the amount is completely wrong. You need to loop over ALL quantities. Look at my answer

Comment: That means it is partially not working, like your code is not checking the checkboxes at all.

Comment: It is now I fixed the === to =

Comment: check my code now, i also fixed it, and if you think it is fine, please remove the downvote

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that uses delegation

I have assumed id=p-float is the top container and I take the price from the p-price div

I have removed a few `</br>` and `<br/>` They are not needed and some of them were not valid HTML and got in the way of the next and previous ElementSiblings

I changed center to CSS and removed the inline onclick

I have quoted the image `alt` attribute

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  const sm = document.getElementById("thesum"); // this never changes
  document.getElementById("p-float").addEventListener("input", function(e) { // I assume p-float is the top container
    const tgt = e.target; // this is the item that changed
    if (tgt.classList.contains("amn")) { // is it an "amn"? 
      const val = +tgt.value;
      const parent = tgt.parentNode; // get the div it sits in 
      parent.nextElementSibling.querySelector(".bought").checked = val > 0; // set the relative checkbox
    }
    let sum = 0;
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".amn")].forEach(amn => { // sum all amns
      const parent = amn.parentNode;
      let floatprice = parseFloat(parent.previousElementSibling.textContent.slice(1)); // take the price from the price above
      sum += +amn.value * floatprice;
    })
    sm.innerHTML = sum.toString(); //put the sum next to the cart 
  });
});
```

```css
.p-float-in {
  text-align: center;
}

.p-float img { height: 120px }
```

```html
<!-- a shopping cart which displays my product sum -->
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/shop-cart/48/shop-cart-apply-icon.png" id="cart" alt=c art/> = <span id="thesum"> </span> (price of selected products)
<!-- an instance of a product (I have a total of six books) -->

<div id="p-float">

  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://www.deslegte.com/images/cached/resample/jpg/data/uploads/594/900/cms_visual_1150794.jpg_1552736675000_594x900.jpg" alt="subtle_art" /><br/>
      <div class="p-name">Subtle Art of not giving a F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$7.99</div>
      <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" name="num" value="amount " min="1" max="5" /> </div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://s.s-bol.com/imgbase0/imagebase3/large/FC/8/8/5/6/9200000095426588.jpg" alt="every" /><br/>
      <div class="p-name">Everything is <br/> F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$8.99</div>
      <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" name="num" value="amount" min="1" max="5" /> </div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://media.s-bol.com/DpVDn5wMm6q/450x840.jpg" alt="deepw" /><br/>
      <div class="p-name">Deep </br>Work </div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://media.s-bol.com/RWmgDpyPwZw/550x836.jpg" alt "gnt"/><br/>
      <div class="p-name">Awaken the giant within</div>
      <div class="p-price">$10.99</div>
      <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" name="num" value="amount " min="1" max="5" /> </div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://media.s-bol.com/YEpBRDx0979Y/550x839.jpg" /><br/>
      <div class="p-name">7 Habits of highly effective people</div>
      <div class="p-price">$29.99</div>
      <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" name="num" value="amount " min="1" max="5" /> </div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://media.s-bol.com/Ykq6ykYR1DO/550x839.jpg" alt="any" /><br/>
      <div class="p-name">Achieve anything in 1 year</div>
      <div class="p-price">$39.99</div>
      <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" onchange="updatetotal()" name="num" value="amount " min="1" max="5" /> </div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery version

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  const $sm = $("#thesum"); // this never changes
  $("#p-float").on("input", ".amn", function(e) { // I assume p-float is the top container
      const val = +this.value;
      $(this).closest(".p-float-in").find(".bought").attr("checked",val > 0); // set the relative checkbox
    let sum = 0;
    $(".amn").each(function() { // using .map here could be interesting too
      let floatprice = parseFloat($(this).closest(".p-float-in").find(".p-price").text().slice(1)); // take the price from the price above
      sum += +this.value * floatprice;
    })
    $sm.html("$"+sum.toString()); //put the sum next to the cart 
  });
});
```

```css
.p-float-in {
  text-align: center;
}

.p-float img { height: 120px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- a shopping cart which displays my product sum -->
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/shop-cart/48/shop-cart-apply-icon.png" id="cart" alt=c art/> = <span id="thesum"> </span> (price of selected products)
<!-- an instance of a product (I have a total of six books) -->

<div id="p-float">

  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://www.deslegte.com/images/cached/resample/jpg/data/uploads/594/900/cms_visual_1150794.jpg_1552736675000_594x900.jpg" alt="subtle_art" /><br/>
      <div class="p-name">Subtle Art of not giving a F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$7.99</div>
      <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" name="num" value="amount " min="1" max="5" /> </div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://s.s-bol.com/imgbase0/imagebase3/large/FC/8/8/5/6/9200000095426588.jpg" alt="every" /><br/>
      <div class="p-name">Everything is <br/> F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$8.99</div>
      <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" name="num" value="amount" min="1" max="5" /> </div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://media.s-bol.com/DpVDn5wMm6q/450x840.jpg" alt="deepw" /><br/>
      <div class="p-name">Deep </br>Work </div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://media.s-bol.com/RWmgDpyPwZw/550x836.jpg" alt "gnt"/><br/>
      <div class="p-name">Awaken the giant within</div>
      <div class="p-price">$10.99</div>
      <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" name="num" value="amount " min="1" max="5" /> </div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://media.s-bol.com/YEpBRDx0979Y/550x839.jpg" /><br/>
      <div class="p-name">7 Habits of highly effective people</div>
      <div class="p-price">$29.99</div>
      <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" name="num" value="amount " min="1" max="5" /> </div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <img class="p-img" src="https://media.s-bol.com/Ykq6ykYR1DO/550x839.jpg" alt="any" /><br/>
      <div class="p-name">Achieve anything in 1 year</div>
      <div class="p-price">$39.99</div>
      <div class="amount"> Amount:<input type="number" class="amn" onchange="updatetotal()" name="num" value="amount " min="1" max="5" /> </div>
      <div class="buyme"> <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: P-float is the container of all my products together . It doesn't work in your code snippet.

Comment: I fixed the issue with === in the checking of the checkbox, it works great now

Comment: you mean  parent.nextElementSibling.querySelector(".bought").checked  === val > 0; ?

Comment: Yes, that was wrong - it's now corrected to `parent.nextElementSibling.querySelector(".bought").checked = val > 0;`

Comment: @VasilisSkentos I posted you a jQuery version too in case you want something that is easier to read

Comment: thank you very much but we haven't done jquery at uni yet and we are not allowed to use it .

Comment: PS: This `[...document.querySelectorAll(".amn")].forEach` can be written `document.querySelectorAll(".amn").forEach` in most new browsers

Comment: i appended the javascript code inside the body with <script> tags yet when I run my program nothing happens .  Is my importing method wrong ?

Comment: I do not know. Any errors in the console? Because I use the window addEventListener, the script can be placed anywhere

Comment: I am using notepad++.It's just that when i change a quantity nothing happens

Comment: Which answer did you actually use the most?

Comment: Kostik's was right on point after putting a new div tag on each product . His code worked when I put the product div he has on his code.

Answer (score -1):

```js
(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.p-float').forEach((rootNode) => {
    const amountField = rootNode.querySelector('.amn');
    amountField.addEventListener('change', onAmountChanged, false);
    amountField.addEventListener('input', onAmountChanged, false);

    const buyMeCheckbox = rootNode.querySelector('.bought');

    function onAmountChanged() {
      const value = parseInt(amountField.value, 10);
      if (Number.isNaN(value)) {
        // TODO calc the values and update other elements
        buyMeCheckbox.removeAttribute('checked');
        return;
      }

      // TODO calc the values and update other elements
      buyMeCheckbox.setAttribute('checked', '');
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<img src="IMAGES/shopcart.png" id="cart" alt=c art/> = <span id="thesum"></span>

<div class="p-float">
  <div class="p-float-in">
    <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\work.jpg" alt=d eepw/><br/>
      <div class="p-name">Deep </br>Work</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
      <div class="amount">
        <span>Amount:</span>
        <input type="number" class="amn" name="num" value="amount" min="1" max="5" /></div>
      <br/>
      <div class="buyme">
        <input type="checkbox" class="bought" name="box" value="buy me" /> Buy Me
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much .But it works only for my first element in the page . These are commands I haven't seen yet . How can you use this for every element ?

Comment: You really need to explain your code and make a snippet. It likely does not work for more than one set of divs

Comment: @VasilisSkentos

>These are commands I haven't seen yet
Which?

>But it works only for my first element in the page
I use the HTML code which you provided.
If you need a more specific solution IMO you should provide a more specific HTML code. If there are several .p-float nodes then

document.querySelectorAll('.p-float').forEach((rootNode) => {
  const amountField = rootNode.querySelector('.amn');
  const buyMeCheckbox = rootNode.querySelector('.bought');

  // other code is the same
});

Comment: @kostik In javascript

Comment: The answer was changed for the case if there are several .p-float nodes

Comment: but it does not sum anything

Comment: @ksotik Thank you very much . It now works . It doesn't sum my products however but I can work on it with this code .

Comment: @mplungjan

sapienti sat :)

Answer (score -1):

You have many flaws in your code but to answer your main question how to tick a checkbox of the product which quantity was updated automatically, a hint -> `quantities[i].value !== ''`, should help you further.

If you do this `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('amn')[0]);`, then look at the property `value`, what do you see? A string, not null. That is why this if statement is `true` to all your checkboxes and get checked.

```js
function updatetotal() {
  var quantities = document.getElementsByClassName("amn");
  var sum = 0;
  var floatprice = parseFloat("9.99");
  var sm = document.getElementById("thesum");
  var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("bought");
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (quantities[i].value !== "") { //this is were all boxes in the page are checked and I want only the boxes with amounts not null to be checked
      boxes[i].checked = true;
    }
    sum += quantities[i].value * floatprice;
  }
  sm.innerHTML = sum.toString(); //put the sum next to the cart 
}
```

```html
<!-- a shopping cart which displays my product sum -->
<img src="IMAGES/shopcart.png" id="cart" alt=c art/> = <span id="thesum"> </span> (price of selected products) <!-- I have a total of six books -->


  <div id="p-float">
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\subtle.jpg" alt = subtle_art/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Subtle Art of not giving an F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class="amn" onchange = "updatetotal()"  name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\everything.jpg" alt = every/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Everything is <br/> F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" onchange = "updatetotal()" class = "amn" name = "num"  value = "amount" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>
  
      <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\work.jpg" alt = deepw/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Deep </br>Work </div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number"  class="amn" onchange = "updatetotal()" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>
    
 
   <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\giant.jpg" alt = gnt/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Awaken the giant within</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number"  class="amn" onchange = "updatetotal()" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div> 
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\habits.jpg" alt = hbts/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">7 Habits of highly effective people</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class = "amn" onchange = "updatetotal()" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me" /> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>
      
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\anything.jpg" alt = any/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Achieve anything in 1 year</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class="amn" onchange = "updatetotal()" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>
      
  </div>
```